# Django Crispy Forms rearrange layout and retain Bootstrap inline formatting?

Tags: django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I am currently working on a Django project and am using cripsy-forms to format and display the HTML forms in conjunction with Bootstrap. If I allow Crispy-Forms to use the default layout order, it will (for the most part) format the correct HTML layout to utilize inline forms with Bootstrap.

In order to rearrange the order of the fields on the form, I am attempting to utilize the Layout helper. When I add the Layout helper, Crispy-Forms loses it's inline labeling ability and all labels are displayed above their field counterparts.

How can I get Crispy Forms to re-order the layout and still retain Bootstrap inline formatting?

```
class MyEntryForm(ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyEntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.form_id = 'id-MyEntryForm'
    self.helper.help_text_inline = True
    self.helper.error_text_inline = True
    self.form_show_labels = True
    self.helper.form_method = 'post'
    self.helper.form_action = 'submit'
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
    self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
    self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'

    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        'field1',
        'field3',
        'field2',

    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `fields` attribute? The generated Form class will have a form field [in the order specified in the fields attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-order-of-fields).

```
class MyEntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = "mymodel"
        fields = ['field1', 'field3', 'field2']
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I was trying to use the Crispy-Forms solution of Layout helper, and totally forgot about fields.Thanks @arocks!